# Flow of ordinary differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, partial-differential-equations

Assume that $b$ is bounded and H\"older continuous, $\delta>0$ be small enough. Then, the solution $X_t(x)$ to the ordinary differential equation
$$
d X_t=b(X_t)dt, X_0=x
$$
forms a flow. Now let $f\in L^1(R^n)$. The question is, does the function
$$
g(x):=f(X_t(x))=f\bigg(x+\int_0^\delta b(X_s(x))ds\bigg)
$$
also belongs to $L^1$??($\delta$ can be small enough)

Comment: If You assume that $b$ is merely Holder continuous than there is no uniqueness of solutions so in general there is no flow. However, if $b$ is Lipschitz then using the change of variables formula one obtains

Comment: Ok, many thanks for your help.